# postgres: error: db doesnt exist ( psql create user case senstivity issue)

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have this database `triviaDB` that i am connecting to from a flask-sqlalchemy `'postgresql://devuser:devpass@localhost:5432/triviaDB'`however it's giving me a programing error psycopg2: auth not allowed.

so i use the following commands in psql to try and give `devuser` authorization on this database but here is the problem
when i run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE triviaDB to devuser;` iget this error:
`ERROR:  database "triviadb" does not exist`
when i quote the db name `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE 'triviaDB' TO devuser;` i get this :
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'triviaDB'"`

Comment: seems you need to get rid of the quotes around triviaDB

Comment: yeah but then i get an error database doesnt exist(first one in the post), i can connect with postgres user ni problems.

Answer (score 1):

If the DB name was created with upper cases, you need to use double quotes:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "triviaDB" to devuser;
```